# UITableView Section Index doesn't respond

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a table view which has section indexes enabled.  All the indexes are showing properly, however I can't get the search icon to actually respond.  The picture on the left shows as high as the table will scroll after using the section index scroll bar on the right, but it should show up with the right hand side design.  Any help would be much appreciated!!

[image: Left side shows what happens when I scroll through the section index. It stops at A, but I want the search icon to result in the table view scrolling to the top]

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you please clarify?

Comment: Are you using SearchDisplayController or simple SearchBar? Do not attach the  SearchBar to your tableView. keep it separate from UITableView.

Comment: All the section indexes in the section index scroll area on the right hand side work aside from the search icon.  How do I enable the search icon to result in the tableview scrolling to the top?

Comment: @Control-V Yes, I'm using the the searchdisplaycontroller ... I want it to scroll off the screen though when the user scrolls through the table, how can i accomplish that without it being in the UITableView?

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to say, you do not want to overlap your section title on SearchBar ? If you do not want then first place the UISeachBar and the place the UITableView (table view y position should start from SearchBar height end)

Comment: No ... I'm saying if I do what you originally suggested (moving the search bar out of the UITableView) it will stay in the same location when the user scrolls through the table. I would prefer that the search box moves off screen when the user scrolls through the table.

Comment: Do not use the SearchDisplayController becuase it has their own searc table view. just use the simple searchbar.

Comment: But why you want to move the SearchBar for offscreen t(Is there anything wrong to show always twitter,facebook etc section stick to top). the image on right hand side looks fine for me(as a general use) except the section index title appearing on search bar? thats why i prefer to people read on http://bit.ly/awcxrz

Comment: @Control-V have you used Apple's own Contacts app?  Where does the SearchBar go when you move down through your contacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always done custom scrolling for the search bar in this case and returned -1 from the delegate method.

My tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex: looks like this - not sure if there's a better way, though:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tv sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSInteger section = -1;
    if ([title isEqualToString:UITableViewIndexSearch]) {
        CGRect searchBarFrame = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.frame;
        [tv scrollRectToVisible:searchBarFrame animated:NO];
    }
    else {
        section = whatever logic you use to determine section
    }
    return section;
}
```

BTW, this is using a the searchDisplayController property.